# Embedding Silverlight control in asp.net and pass the parameter dynamically

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a silverlight control with an Expression Player where a specific method is exposed for use in javascript:

```
[ScriptableMember]
        public void PlayMedia(string mediaFileUri)
        {
            PlaylistItem playListItem = new PlaylistItem();
            playListItem.MediaSource = new Uri(mediaFileUri);
            myPlayer.Playlist.Items.Add(playListItem);
            myPlayer.Playlist.AutoPlay = true;
        }
```

. 
Then I want to embed this silverlight control in my asp.net application. I do it this way:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object id="silverlightPlayer" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightPlayer.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

Additionally, I have a javascript method, to to load the media file dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PlayMedia(mediaFileUri) {
        var silverlightPlayer = document.getElementById("silverlightPlayer");
        if (silverlightPlayer == null) {
            alert("Silverlight player not loaded");
        }
        else {
            alert("Silverlight player loaded");
            silverlightPlayer.content.SilverlightPlayer.PlayMedia(mediaFileUri);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then when I execute this js method in such way:

```
<body onload="PlayMedia('http://mediadl.microsoft.com/mediadl/IISNET/media/BigBuckBunny_1080p24.wmv');">
```

it all works fine.

However I wanted to pass the parameter to my Default.aspx page where the silverlight control is hosted and then compute the url and pass it to the silverlight control. The link could be as follows: http://localhost/Default.aspx?id=21487982

What I did is: I created an appropriate code in Page_Load method to execute the js script, however I get the message: "**Silverlight player loaded**" but afterwards I get an error:" Invalid pointer" in line:

```
silverlightPlayer.content.SilverlightPlayer.PlayMedia(mediaFileUri);
```

My Page_Load method looks as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = Page.Request.QueryString["id"];
            string url = ComputeUrl(id);
            string script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> ";
            script += "PlayMedia('"+url+"')";
            script += "</SCRIPT>";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"ClientScript", script);

        }
```

Can someone please tell me what should I do in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for InitParams
Pass the parameter directly to silverlight. this may help you. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838255%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx